# In VHDL how best to wait for a clock edge in a test bench

Tags: vhdl

When writing test benches, is there any problem with writing

```
wait for 1 ns ; wait until rising_edge( clock ) ;
```

every time I want to wait for the next rising edge?

I'd like to put this sequence in a procedure and then always use it.

The reason I want to wait for 1 ns is that if I simply have the `wait until`s and there is no signal assignment in between two of them, they will collapse into one.

The clock cycle time is 10ns, so 1 ns shouldn't be a problem. What I'd really like to do is wait for one delta, but I don't know how to do that.  Is it possible?

Are there hidden pitfalls to this approach?

We're using VHDL 93 with the ISIM simulator.

Comment: Signal updates are scheduled in an ordered queue (projected output waveform) with a single entry for any simulation time. Simulation time advances when there are no more updates scheduled for the current time (which causes a delta cycle). A signal assignment waveform element without an **after** *time*_expression is the equivalent to **after** 0 ns (all 0 values with a time unit are the same value, the time unit has to be the resolution limit or larger. You don't need the first wait, the order of process resumption is non-deterministic (or at least non-portable).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need the `wait for 1 ns`.

One way to wait for 5 clocks is:

```
wait until rising_edge( clock ) ;
wait until rising_edge( clock ) ;
wait until rising_edge( clock ) ;
wait until rising_edge( clock ) ;
wait until rising_edge( clock ) ;
```

One simplified rule is that the wait statement always suspends the process for at least a simulation/delta cycle.

With a wait `until` that does not have an explicitly supplied `on sensitivity-list` (such as the example above), there is an implied `on sensitivity-list` that has every signal in the `until` clause in it.    Hence, the above is equivalent to:

```
wait on clock until rising_edge( clock ) ; 
wait on clock until rising_edge( clock ) ; 
wait on clock until rising_edge( clock ) ; 
wait on clock until rising_edge( clock ) ; 
wait on clock until rising_edge( clock ) ;
```

Maybe this longer form is a little more obvious - when clock changes and rising_edge( clock ) is true the wait statement will resume and continue to the next wait statement.   The next wait statement suspends until a change on clock occurs.

Comment: Thanks very much.  It seems I misunderstood something. Could I also wait for 5 clocks in a for loop: `for i in 1 to 5 loop wait until rising_edge( clock ); end loop;`?

Comment: Yes the loop will wait 5 cycles. (You can put it in a subprogram and use it multiple times)

Comment: *With wait until there is always an implied sensitivity list (on) that has every signal in the until clause in it.* , e.g. -2008 10.2 Wait statement "wait_statement ::= [ label : ] **wait** [ sensitivity_clause ] [ condition_clause ] [ timeout_clause ] ;" ... "If no sensitivity clause appears, the sensitivity set is constructed according to the following (recursive) rule:...". The condition clause is used to construct the sensitivity list when no sensitivity clause is present. This is testable with a condition clause containing a superset of the sensitivity clause and failing to resume.

Comment: @user16145658 so clarified.   Thanks.   OTOH, the `With wait until` was referencing the previous example and not every `wait until`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `wait for 1 ns` is useless. With or without it will not change anything as long as the clock period is larger than 1 ns and you execute this more than 1 ns before the next rising edge of the clock. To wait for a number of rising edges of the clock you could define a procedure in the declarative region of your architecture:

```vhdl
procedure waitNre(n: positive) is
begin
  for i in 1 to n loop
    wait until rising_edge(clk);
  end loop;
end procedure waitNre;
```

And then:

```vhdl
waitNre(5);
```

to wait for 5 rising edges of `clk`. If you want to share this among designs put the procedure's declaration/definition in a package and add the clock signal to the procedure's inputs:

```vhdl
procedure waitNre(signal clock: std_ulogic; n: positive) is
begin
  for i in 1 to n loop
    wait until rising_edge(clock);
  end loop;
end procedure waitNre;
```

And then:

```vhdl
waitNre(MyClk, 5);
```

As noted by Jim in a comment you could also declare the `n` parameter as an integer such that calling the procedure with a 0 or negative value would simply skip the loop (no wait). Or as a natural, if you know for sure that calling the procedure with a negative value indicates a coding error somewhere.

Comment: In OSVVM's TbUtilPkg, we have WaitForClock, which is almost identical to yours excepts we allow n to be an integer.   Values 0 or less result in a null range which never loops - so it waits for 0 clocks.

Comment: @JimLewis Good point, thanks Jim. I would probably prefer a natural than an integer, because personally, if I call this kind of procedure with a negative parameter, it is likely an error of mine, but this is a matter of coding habits. I will add your suggestion to this (old) answer.

Comment: I probably need to re-think my aversion to using type natural.   I suspect I like it here.   OTOH, I don't like depending on objects to initialize to a particular value.   I would rather manually initialize them as a declaration of intent and that it is a requirement that they start at this value.